# Invalid Argument while Creating Socket

Tags: android, c, network-programming

I'm facing problem while creating a socket, with configuration as mentioned below,
Code :

```
sid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Error Details : `Number - 22, String - Invalid argument`

The error is not quite consistent. Out of 10 run this will happen for 3 - 4 times.
The code is compiled for the Android OS (For MAC & Windows platform it work for 10 out of 10).
Please suggest the possible reason and also fix for this.

Comment: You might like to show us how you test for error.

Comment: There is no specific way to simulate this problem, it is inconsistent. If the same socket code is run on multiple thread, "may be" in a thread or two it fails, or it "may" just work fine if the app is restarted.

Comment: The code snippet used to get the failure is "if (INVALID_SOCKET == sid){printf("Number - %d, String - %s", errno, strerror(errno));}"

Answer (score -1):

Please check the permission of directory/path from where your executable run. 
see this link for similar error and fix on windows

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wsk/thread/3076a9cd-57a0-418d-8de1-07adc3b486bb/

Comment: I doubt a "windows bug" causes a socket mal function on android.

Comment: @alk: I am not saying its window bug on android. I just suggested it could be permission issue.

Comment: I doubt if it is a permission issue, if it is the case, ideally error should happen every time and not occasionally. Also I'm installing the APK on the android device and executing it from there. The logs are written / received form the device. I doubt it has to do with the permission on device(I may be wrong).